# How do I make my archive page look like popular reviewing sites (e.g., Polygon and Gamespot)

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-post-type-archives, archive-template

To further clarify my question: Reviewing sites like Polygon have sections where you click on Reviews, and it shows you a page with a grid of all their reviews (latest will be at the top though). They usually have a thumbnail of the game on the left, some text in the middle, and then a score on the right. Here's an [example](http://www.gamespot.com/reviews/).

I actually made a page like this with the slug "review". I also have a custom post type with the slug "reviews". I used a page builder plugin (Beaver) to make "review" look exactly like a popular reviewing site's review page, but the problem with this is that it won't make new pages for every x amount of posts (i.e., it doesn't do what archive pages do: show all your latest posts and make a new page when you it displays the max amount of posts that you want to be shown on a page). So I'd have to create the page titled "review/2", and then I'd also have to add pagination at the bottom to make it link to the next page. Also, I have to manually update any of the pages with the slug "review". This is how it looks like: [image: review].

To clarify on the image, I use a thumbnail on the left (not a featured image), a text editor in the middle, and another image on the right (not a featured image).

Now, "reviews" isn't like this; the way the archive is formatted is just like a blog's home page: have the header of the post, the content of the post, and the footer of that post. I would love it if I could just modify the archive page of "reviews" to look like "review", which would then also automatically update whenever I made a new review, and get rid of "review".

I have the archive-reviews.php and content-reviews.php already set up, I just want to know if it's possible for me to get my archive page for "reviews" to look like the "review" page.

In conclusion:
Can you either...

1. shed light on how review sites get their review pages to look like that and maybe I can implement that into my archive page
2. or... tell me if I should just do it the long and manual way
3. or... give me insight into how I can get my "reviews" archive page to look like my "review" page, which I provided you an image of.

P.S. Sorry for the wordiness! Ask for clarification if you need any.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to me the desire to use that page-builder plugin has resulted in a solution far more complicated, laborious, and convoluted than whatever you're calling the "long and manual way" :P . WordPress itself answers your question.

---

### WordPress Philosophy

Pages are for static, timeless, and potentially hierarchical content. Plugins abuse that notion sometimes, but never mind that.

A collection of content with the same properties is called an "archive". Archives can be ordered, filtered, paginated (displayed across a number of "pages") - and *WordPress does every one of things **really** well out of the box*.

WordPress theme templates give you full control over the way content is displayed by way of direct HTML, PHP, and CSS. The [Template Hierarchy](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/) provides a simple model for organizing which files display what content. [The Loop](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/the-loop/) provides a mechanism for accessing all the properties of a particular piece of content.

---

### Solution

Unless you have more constraints and needs that have yet to be mentioned, the only reasonable solution is to:

1. delete that "review" `page` and forget it ever existed. It's absurdity to try to turn a `page` into an archive when WordPress's built-in archives already fulfill all of your needs.
2. modify your `archive-reviews.php` theme template file and associated CSS to achieve your desired appearance; possibly `functions.php`as well if WordPress is not "behaving" as you wish. If your reviews archive doesn't look right, then you're not yet done with your `archive-reviews.php` file and CSS styles - it's as simple as that.

Read up on [Theme Development](https://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development) and [Template Tags](https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags) if you're struggling to understand what's going on in your theme files.

Comment: Thank you for the Wordpress Philosophy; given the blockade I've gotten from using a Page, it makes a lot of sense. And i was referring to using a page builder plugin as the long and manual way. I was using this way before I knew that what an archive page was, but once I figured it out, I noticed the flaws in my old way. I was confused about how I might do all the images on my archive page, but the template tags helped me out! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This is a little hard to follow (*review/reviews/review/reviews* :), but the main issue I spot is that you want a page page to act as an archive of CPT. This doesn't really work cleanly and normal functionality is going to be missing (such as pagination as you have noticed).

If you want CPT to have an archive you should be just registering it with archive support. Look up `has_archive` and related bits in [`register_post_type()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type) documentation.

However if your requirements are complicated you might need to have to build permalinks and query for it from scratch.

Comment: Sorry about the confusion. Just to reclarify: I have two pages: the page I showed above where I would post links to the reviews and the archive page for the reviews (reviews is the CPT). It seems like your second paragraph is telling me that I should create an archive page, but if that's so, I already have one. 

But your first paragraph is correct, I tried to use a page page as an archive, but lack of pagination makes me want to use a customized archive, which I have. So I think my problem lies with your third paragraph. How would I query my archive page to look like the picture above?

Comment: I understand this question is pretty BIG ("How would I query my archive page to look like the picture above?"), but the reason I ask it is because I cannot wrap my head around how I would make an archive look like the picture above. The images in particular is what's making it hard for me to comprehend. How would I be able to make my reviews loop with their thumbnail to the left and their review score to the right? Maybe if I were using featured images, I could make it work, but these aren't featured images.

Comment: I think you are overly (and prematurely) focused on how it _looks_. Looks are a final stage, data architecture comes before that. I don't quite follow why you have _two_ locations that _both_ sound like a list of reviews.

Comment: Before I created a custom post-type **reviews**, I had a page on my site called Reviews that I was going to use to feature any **posts** that were reviews. I then figured out I could make a post type called **reviews**, and I did.

This created a problem because with the custom post-type **reviews** came an archive page with the slug "reviews", which was the same as the page I already had. I changed the page that I already had to the slug "review". I will upload photos to show you this difference.

As for your new comment, it confuses me. Are you sure I am prematurely focusing on looks?